# openvideodecode / unified video decoder

Tags: h.264, amd-gpu

Can anyone tell if the AMD OpenDecode API (`ovdecodegetdeviceinfo(...)` etc.) is still supported? I could not find it in the latest Media SDK ( 3.0 Beta ), but there was no explicit deprecation mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AMD developer forum a user/moderator states

> OpenVideo is deprecated. Media SDK is better choice for video encode
>   and decode.